# D3 4.0+ does not create a global d3 variable when imported into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, jupyter-notebook

The following will fail with a JavaScript `ReferenceError`:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

display(HTML("""
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<script>
console.log(d3);
</script>
"""))
```

Why is that?

The equivalent D3 version 3.x will work (albeit on the second try, for me):

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

display(HTML("""
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script>
console.log(d3);
</script>
"""))
```

[This](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2615) is the most relevant question/answer I could find on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be due to an internal change to the way that `d3` exports itself. 3.x branch versions of `d3` exported all of their internals as global variables ([source code](https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js)); 4.x branch versions no longer do that ([source code](https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js)). A package manager (like `require.js`) is expected instead now, and exports are piped to that instead.

Further details are in the [requisite GitHub issue](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2615).

What you should do instead now is something like:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>var d3 = require('d3')</script>
```

After that, everything should work as expected.

Comment: just to highlight the fact that Jupyter already make use of require.js, and without require.config, the above code may be too simplified to work (where would require find d3?). Anyway it raises errors when I tested.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution described here:

http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/09/interactive-d3v4js-in-jupyter-notebook.html

Essentially you need to use **require.js** .. which is already available through the notebook's own infrastructure.