# Should this code override the default d3 version in use by Juypyter notebooks?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load the latest version of D3JS in a Jupyter notebook using a Python Kernel,
so I can use D3 in the subsequent cells that contain javascript code executed via %%javascript cell magic.
So I am doin something like this in a cell

```
import json
from IPython.core.display import HTML,Javascript
HTML(
'''
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
'''
)
str1="<nodedata>"+json.dumps(json_lab['nodes'])+"</nodedata>"
str2="<linkdata>"+json.dumps(json_lab['links'])+"</linkdata>"
HTML(str1+str2)
Javascript('console.log(d3)')
```

However I get this response showing an older version there

[image]
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

"This is the way"
[d3.js Loading version 3 vs version 4 in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714017/d3-js-loading-version-3-vs-version-4-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
%%javascript
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v7'
  }
});
    require(['d3'], function(d3) {
        window.d3 = d3;
    });
```